# Bootstrap - data-toggle attribute when multiple buttons exist

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have several buttons. When a user clicks any button I want to give him the impression that the button is clicked .

This is the code:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th><button class="btn btn-danger" >Today</button></th>
<th><button class="btn btn-danger" >Tomorrow</button></th>
<th><button class="btn btn-danger" >DayAfterTomorrow</button></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

And this works when I have a single button:

```
<button class="btn" data-toggle="button">Today</button>
```

If the user clicks on tomorrow, the data-toggle attribute still remains for the today button. Instead, I want to disable the data-toggle attribute when another button is clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the bootstraps radio button functionality to achieve that effect. Try this:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Today</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Tomorrow</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">DayAfterTomorrow</button>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u7Lg8/

Comment: Great . But only problem is i have the buttons as table headers .

Comment: The source code at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-button.js#L53 selects me closest parent with the data-toggle="buttons-radio" property, deactivates all active links beneath it and then toggles the active link for the pressed button, so it should work if you add data-toggle="buttons-radio" to your header's <tr> tag.

Comment: If you want to toggle via javascript and/or if you don't want to use radio button grouping; you can check my answer for the solution in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    //Removing `data-toggle` from all elements
    $('.btn').removeData('toggle');
    //Adding `data-toggle` on clicked element
    $(this).data('toggle','button');        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the buttons under a div and set the data-toggle on the group.

You can see it in the example page for [Twitter bootstrap buttons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons)

```
<!-- Add data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" for checkbox style toggling on btn-group -->
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button class="btn">Left</button>
  <button class="btn">Middle</button>
  <button class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope . Not what i'm looking for .

Comment: Yeah of course. I forgot to telel you that the data-toggle value need js to get the clicked button value, see @Engineer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with for my site (only way to improve is to NOT use hidden variable to store final value )

```js
     $("input[name='dispatch']").change(function(){
           
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active btn-primary');
            $("#WantsDispatchService").val($(this).val());
            
        });
```

```html
 
  <div class="btn-group btn-toggle  " data-toggle="buttons">
 <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
  <input name="dispatch" value="false" type="checkbox"> No
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-default  btn-sm">

  <input name="dispatch" value="true" type="checkbox"> Yes
 </label>
  
</div>
<input type ="hidden" id="WantsDispatchService" name="WantsDispatchService" value="false"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$().button('toggle')` to toggle button state via javascript.[*](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-methods)

In my case; i can not use grouped buttons, they are visually separate from each other.

I check if the other button is pressed and toggle it back using javascript.
Here is my solution:

```
$('#buttonA').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#buttonB').attr('aria-pressed') == 'true') {
        $('#buttonB').button('toggle');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#buttonB').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#buttonA').attr('aria-pressed') == 'true') {
        $('#buttonA').button('toggle');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```